# How do you effectively parsing about 5,000,000 transactions?

Tags: parser

I need to parsing VERY many transactions at an address, but I can't find an efficient way to do it, can you tell me how to do it?
5,000,000+ transactions

Comment: [We have been parsing more than two hundred million transactions with our Python library](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/). 5M transactions is for ants.